# A ZeroMQ Subscriber does not receive any data in a unittest. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.5, zeromq, python-unittest, pyzmq

I'm failing to understand where my data ends up.

I've written a test to ensure that my `Publisher` class successfully sends data, and that this data is received if I bind to it.

The class itself inherits from `Thread`, and exposes a `publish()` method which I can call to pass data to be broadcasted to subscribers via a `Queue()`.

However, in my test the data never arrives. I've ensured to use the identical
port, and I can't think what else the issue is here.

I'm a ZeroMQ newbie, but I've managed to get `PubSub` patterns to work before.

Test Code:

```
# Import Built-ins
import time
import json
import queue
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

# Import Third-Party
import zmq


def test_publisher_sends_data(self):
    port = 667
    name, topic, data = 'TestNode', 'testing', ['this', 'is', 'data']
    encoded_name = json.dumps(name).encode('utf-8')
    encoded_topic = json.dumps(topic).encode('utf-8')
    encoded_data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    expected_result = (encoded_name, encoded_topic, encoded_data)

    publisher = Publisher(port)
    print("starting publisher")
    publisher.start()

    q = Queue()

    def recv(q):
        ctx = zmq.Context()
        zmq_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
        print("Connecting to publisher")
        zmq_sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:%s' % port)
        while True:
            print("waiting for data..")
            q.put(zmq_sock.recv_multipart())
            print("data received!")
    t = Thread(target=recv, args=(q,))
    t.start()

    print("sending data via publisher")
    for i in range(5):
        self.assertTrue(publisher.publish(name, topic, data))
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("checking q for received data..")
    try:
        result = q.get(block=False)
    except queue.Empty:
        self.fail("Queue was empty, no data received!")
    self.assertEqual(expected_result, result)
```

The `Publisher` Class

```
# Import Built-Ins
import logging
import json
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread, Event

# Import Third-Party
import zmq


class Publisher(Thread):
    """Publisher Class which allows publishing data to subscribers.

    The publishing is realized with ZMQ Publisher sockets, and supports publishing
    to multiple subscribers.

    The run() method continuosly checks for data on the internal q, which is fed
    by the publish() method.

    """
    def __init__(self, port, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize Instance.
        :param port:
        """
        self.port = port
        self._running = Event()
        self.sock = None
        self.q = Queue()
        super(Publisher, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def publish(self, node_name, topic, data):
        """Publish the given data to all current subscribers.

        All parameters must be json-serializable objects
        :param data:
        :return:
        """
        message_parts = [json.dumps(param).encode('utf-8')
                         for param in (node_name, topic, data)]
        if self.sock:
            self.q.put(message_parts)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self._running.clear()
        try:
            self.sock.close()
        except Exception:
            pass
        super(Publisher, self).join(timeout)

    def run(self):
        self._running.set()
        ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
        self.sock.bind("tcp://*:%s" % self.port)
        while self._running.is_set():
            if not self.q.empty():
                msg_parts = self.q.get(block=False)
                print("Sending data:", msg_parts)
                self.sock.send_multipart(msg_parts)
            else:
                continue
        ctx.destroy()
        self.sock = None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, someNonZeroLengthSTRING )`
as

### a documented default `SUB`-socket instance is subscribed to nothing

( naturally )
if any incoming message fails to match any of strings, the `SUB`-side is subscribed to, the local `.recv()` will naturally not receive such one.

Given your code did no explicit subscription, there is no such message, that could meet the topic-filter processing condition, Q.E.D.

---

### The best next step:

As another issue -- A "Late-joiner" trouble -- may happen next, if unittest design is blitz-fast, the best next step I may recommend for your further ( not only ZeroMQ ) distributed-systems designs, is to spend a time with fabulous Pieter HINTJENS' book **"Code Connected, Volume 1"**. Anyone serious into heterogeneous distributed-systems signalling / messaging will enjoy his sharing both technical and non-technical views and opinions.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation! I'll look into it.

Comment: For future reference, "Code Connected" is available as the '0MG - The Guide' with a multitude of examples in various languages [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all) or via the WayBackMachine, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170712150828/http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all).

Comment: For record, I meant **this PDF** http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main:files/cc1pe.pdf + one may enjoy also the accompanying suite of unique, canned pieces of experience from http://hintjens.com/books Almost sure, one may love the read 'em. Good luck with all HFT efforts.

Comment: Funny how Ms. Rowling has changed the original Gerald Durrell meaning of talking parcel. Anyway - the GA research modeling motto got me, totally - *(cit.)* "adjustment to non-stationarities" in principally non-stationary field, that's a point, isn't it? Might be a fair move to somehow diplomatically mention PR/MARCOM people not to cause more collateral damage by similar (almost)-"head-less" points.